# Can you enter Australia on a UK passport that expires within 6 months?

Tags: passports, australia, uk-citizens

We are travelling to Australia in March. My husband is Australian and both myself and my daughter hold UK passports. Her passport expires after we return but the Australian immigration website indicates they 'recommend' at least 6 months on their passport. It is mandatory and are we likely to face any challenges arriving or departing Australia if her passport has less than 6 months?

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**, you can.  [Australian High Commission to Malaysia](http://www.malaysia.highcommission.gov.au/klpr/faq.html#Apply_6mthsValidity):

> *Can I apply if my passport is valid for less than 6 months?*
>
> Yes. However, if you are planning a short stay, it is recommended that
>   your passport should not expire when you are in Australia. You will
>   need a valid passport to leave as well as enter Australia. Even with a
>   valid visa, some airlines may decline to carry passengers whose
>   passport has less than 6 months validity. In addition, the country you
>   are travelling to after you depart Australia may require you to have a
>   passport with more than 6 months validity. You should check with your
>   intended airline and/or travel agent whether it will be an issue.